# How to use vue class component with composition api in Vue2 by typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

```html
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import { CustomerContext, getCustomerRepository } from '@/composables/customerRepository'

@Component
export default class CustomerList extends Vue {
  search = ''

  setup(): CustomerContext {
    const ctx = getCustomerRepository()
    return ctx
  }
}
</script>
```

In Vue 2, I want to use the Composition API with the class component style by TypeScript, but I'm not sure I have the correct syntax. Also, the `setup()` function did not get invoked automatically.

Can `vue-class-component` work with the Compostion API in TypeScript?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Vue 2

First, make sure you've installed the [`@vue/composition-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/composition-api) plugin for Vue 2:

```js
// main.ts
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)
```

Then define `setup()` as a `@Component` option (not as a class method):

```js
// MyComponent.vue
@Component({
  setup(props, context) {
    //...
  }
})
export default class CustomerList extends Vue {
  //...
}
```

#### Vue 3

For Vue 3, `vue-class-component@8.x` exports a `setup()` API that you'd assign to a local variable:

```html
<template>
  <div>counter: {{myContext.counter}}</div>
  <button @click="myContext.increment">Increment</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, setup } from 'vue-class-component'
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  myContext = setup(() => {
    const counter = ref(0)

    return {
      counter,
      increment() {
        counter.value++
      }
    }
  })
}
</script>
```

***Note:** As of `vue-class-component@8.0.0-rc.1`, `setup()` receives no arguments, including the [`context` and `props` arguments from the `setup()` used in the Options API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#arguments).*

Answer (score 0):

Use class to write setup, and support vue2 and vue3

```
<template>
    <p>{{ count.text }}</p>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { Setup, Hook } from 'vue-class-setup';

@Setup
class Count {
    public value = 0;
    public get text() {
        return String(this.value);
    }
    @Hook('mounted')
    public init() {
        this.value++;
    }
}

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        return {
            count: new Count()
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

https://github.com/fmfe/vue-class-setup